# Possible Mathematica bug

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, bugs, regions

**Fixed in 13.1**

---

I believe the following two integrals should have the same value, since the `Boole[]` expression always evaluates to `1` in the given range.
However, for some reason the first one returns 0.

Is this a bug? Or am I missing something about how integrals work in Mathematica?

```
In[1]:= Integrate[Boole[u0 <= 1]/(
 Sqrt[u0] Sqrt[u1] Sqrt[u2]), {u0, u1, u2} \[Element] 
  Simplex[{{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}]]

Out[1]= 0

In[2]:= Integrate[1/(
 Sqrt[u0] Sqrt[u1] Sqrt[u2]), {u0, u1, u2} \[Element]
  Simplex[{{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}]]

Out[2]= 2 Sqrt[3] \[Pi]
```

Or with a screenshot for better formatting
[image]

Comment: `Integrate[
 Simplify[Boole[u0 <= 1]/(Sqrt[u0] Sqrt[u1] Sqrt[u2]), 
  Assumptions -> u0 <= 1], {u0, u1, u2} \[Element] 
  Simplex[{{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}]]` returns `2 Sqrt[3] \[Pi]` so this is not a big bug.

Comment: Yes looks like a bug to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bug fixed in 13.1. Screen shot below

[image]